# UILabel displays colors beneath it

Tags: swift, uikit, core-animation

I have a non-transparent **UIView** with **UILabel** of white non-transparent color. I display it as a subview in some view with border. And I can see that border in my **UILabel's** letters...

[image: "y" letter has blended color with my border]

By the way, I've tried to overlap content in my superview and it's been rendered absolutely fine - so the issue is existing only with the border.

I assume there's something wrong on the render layer when it blends border of the superview and letters of the **UILabel**

Code for TagView and it's superview:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

enum TagType {
    case minimal
    case rounded
    case circle
}

class TagView: UIView {
    var tagType: TagType = .rounded { didSet { updateUI() }}
    var isSelected = false { didSet { updateUI() }}

    private(set) lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .semibold)
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }
    
    private var leadingLabelAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    private var trailingLabelAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    
    private var topLabelAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    private var bottomLabelAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

    var constantValue: CGFloat {
        tagType == .circle ? 12 : 8
    }
    
    var verticalInsetTop: CGFloat {
        tagType == .minimal ? 3 : 5
    }
    
    var verticalInsetBottom: CGFloat {
        tagType == .minimal ? 3 : 7
    }

    private func setup() {
        clipsToBounds = true
        addSubview(label)
        leadingLabelAnchor = label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: constantValue)
        trailingLabelAnchor = label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -constantValue)
        leadingLabelAnchor?.priority = .defaultHigh
        leadingLabelAnchor?.isActive = true
        trailingLabelAnchor?.priority = .defaultHigh
        trailingLabelAnchor?.isActive = true
        
        topLabelAnchor = label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: verticalInsetTop)
        topLabelAnchor?.isActive = true
        
        bottomLabelAnchor = label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -verticalInsetBottom)
        bottomLabelAnchor?.isActive = true
        
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        updateUI()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateUI()
    }
    
    private func updateUI() {
        leadingLabelAnchor?.constant = constantValue
        trailingLabelAnchor?.constant = -constantValue
        
        topLabelAnchor?.constant = verticalInsetTop
        bottomLabelAnchor?.constant = -verticalInsetBottom
        
        backgroundColor = isSelected ? .blue : .clear
        label.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        label.textColor = isSelected ? .white : .blue
        
        switch tagType {
        case .minimal:
            layer.cornerRadius = 10
        case .rounded:
            layer.cornerRadius = 12
        case .circle:
            layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
        }
    }

    func configure(with text: String) {
        label.text = text
    }
}

final class MyControl: UIControl {
    private lazy var tagView: TagView = {
        let view = TagView()
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        tagView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tagView.isSelected = true
        backgroundColor = .clear
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        
        addSubview(tagView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            [
                tagView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
                tagView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: -16)
            ]
        )
        
        tagView.configure(with: "7 dayyyyy")
    }
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.textColor = .black
        
        let myControl = MyControl()
        myControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(myControl)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            myControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            myControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            myControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        ])
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Comment: How are you setting the constraints? Are you specifying a height for the '7 days trial' UILabel, or are you letting the code figure it out?

Comment: Why wouldn't you add the Label above UIView in the same view hierarchy?

Comment: @devPau I'm not specifying the height, it relies on intrinsic content size, I don't think it's linked to the problem

Comment: @son it's already above UIView in the same hierarchy with not transparent background

Comment: Could you give us the code regarding this UIView? I recreated it and it renders fine.

Comment: Hmm, so weird, I doubt it. How can lower view overlay upper view? Can you share more code or simply debug UI to see what's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried setting the border and label to different colors to ensure the letters are being cutoff by the views overlapping and not from the `lineBreakMode` set on the `UILabel`?  I would try setting `label.lineBreakMode = .ByCharWrapping`, if you haven't already

Comment: @clawesome it didn't help, also I've attached sample code which reproduces the issue

Answer (score 0):

Only workaround I found for now, not to apply to parent view's layer border width and color, but to add additional subview with border to this parent views so **the tag view is not a subview of a new background bordered view**:

```
final class MyControl: UIControl {
...
    private func setup() {
        // layer.cornerRadius = 10
        // layer.borderWidth = 2
        // layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = .white
        backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        backgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        backgroundView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        
        addSubview(backgroundView)
        addSubview(tagView)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're drawing on top of your view.  If you add a subview and do the drawing on it, you won't have the overlapping issue.

```
    final class MyControl: UIControl {
        private lazy var borderView: UIView = {
            let view = UIView()
            return view
        }()
      
        private lazy var tagView: TagView = {
            let view = TagView()
            return view
        }()
        
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            setup()
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        
        private func setup() {
            borderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            borderView.backgroundColor = .clear
            borderView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            borderView.layer.borderWidth = 2
            borderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            addSubview(borderView)
          
            tagView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            tagView.isSelected = true
            backgroundColor = .clear
            
            addSubview(tagView)
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
                [
                    borderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
                    borderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
                    borderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                    borderView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
                  
                    tagView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
                    tagView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: -16)
                ]
            )
            
            tagView.configure(with: "7 dayyyyy")
        }
    }
```